# Initiate dialog using Dialogflow, Twilio & Node Js.

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

I am trying to find a way to trigger a Dialogflow event from Node Js to start a conversation with the end user.

For example, I'd like to send a text message to the end user reminding them about their appointment and ask them for a confirmation.

As I understand it, I would need to initiate the conversation with the end user, and programatically set the entities and context in Dialogflow. Any insights on how I might achieve this?

i.e.

DIALOGFLOW AGENT: Hi John, I'd like to confirm you appointment for 2pm this Thursday?

Comment: Please go through this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzOvU_DylZg

Comment: Thanks for sharing the video and it doesn't answer my query.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow doesn't currently support proactively sending messages on any platforms.   You can send your own messages via the platform's API and any responses to that message will be received by your Dialogflow agent and responded to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up creating logic on my backend to emulate the functionality of dialog flow and handoff control to dialog flow depending on the reply by the user. 